# List of source members in a file with SQL

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

Is it possible to generate a list of all source members within an iSeries source file using SQL?

Might be similar to getting table definitions from SYSTABLES and SYSCOLUMNS, but I'm unable to find anything so far.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, try asking over on the [MIDRANGE-L mailing list](http://lists.midrange.com/listinfo/midrange-l).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly SQL doesn't know anything about members, so all the sourcefile-info you could get from qsys2.syscolumns is, that they consist of three columns.

you want the member info and i suggest using the qshell( STRQSH ) together with a query to qsys2.systables as source files are specially marked there.

```
select table_schema , table_name from qsys2.systables where File_type = 'S'
```

i whacked together a qshell one-liner for copy&paste purposes ..

```
db2 -S "select '/QSYS.LIB/' concat table_schema concat '.LIB/' concat table_name concat '.FILE' from qsys2.systables where File_type = 'S'" | grep '/' | xargs -n1 find >/home/myuser/myfile
```

it pipes every member it finds to the IFS directory /home/myuser/myfile you could also specify a Sourcefile member. feel free to modify to your needs.

PS: it throws errors for Sourcefiles directly sitting in /QSYS.LIB, but i think you don't want those anyway..

take care! :)

Answer (score 11):

More tables and views have been added to the system catalog since the other answers were presented. Now, you can get the list of members (a.k.a. "partitions" in SQL parlance) for a given file (a.k.a. table) like this:

```
SELECT TABLE_PARTITION FROM SYSPARTITIONSTAT
WHERE TABLE_NAME = myfile AND TABLE_SCHEMA = mylib
```

You can also get other information from `SYSPARTITIONSTAT` such as the number of rows in each member, and timestamps for the last change, save, restore, or use.

Comment: This is the information I was looking for today.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a CL program that retrieves the list of members using the DSPFD command. Perhaps you can call that program from a stored procedure?

Answer (score 2):

Just used this, it works a treat.

```
DSPFD FILE(Libname/Filename)
      TYPE(*MBRLIST)         
      OUTPUT(*OUTFILE)       
      OUTFILE(QTEMP/MBRLIST)
```

then in SQL

```
SELECT MLNAME FROM MBRLIST
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @john-y's answer, you can also get a list of source physical file members like this:

```
SELECT SYSTEM_TABLE_MEMBER, SOURCE_TYPE FROM QSYS2/SYSPARTITIONSTAT WHERE
SYSTEM_TABLE_SCHEMA = 'MYLIB' AND SYSTEM_TABLE_NAME = 'QRPGLESRC'
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, for just library and source file:

```
SELECT sys_dname, sys_tname    
FROM qsys2/systables         
ORDER BY sys_dname, sys_tname
```

However, for more detail, a procedure is outlined in [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.sys.ibm.as400.misc/nThciz0QS58).

Comment: @chappjc Just to confirm - Your edit was to format the SQL statements in a code-block and to convert the explicit discussion URL to a hyperlink beneath the text "this discussion"? My apologies as I neaten my formatting.

Comment: Yes.  See the [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22822770/revisions) to view changes.

Comment: A somewhat more advanced procedure is described in [The power of user-defined table functions](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibmi/library/i-power-of-udtf/). See the section describing the ListMember_Fnc UDTF.

Answer (score 0):

I need it to find where an specific source member was located, the RPGLE program has /COPY #IFSIO_H, but Its not qualified from which Source File. Therefore, I had to write a quick QSH to find the specific source member in all libraries, starting from QSYS.LIB: This only works if within the Member has the string.

```
find '/QSYS.LIB/' -name '*.MBR' -exec  grep -rins  '#IFSIO_H'  {} \;
```

It takes time, the grep and find are submitted to batch